# Modern approaches to multiprocess services as opposed to multithreading

Tags: linux, multithreading, architecture, concurrency, bsd

Having been around for the past 15 years, I'm very familiar with the multiprocess vs. multithread debate, and personally prefer using threads 10:1. However, some situations almost scream with the need to use multiple or even many processes. Has there been any serious breakthroughs in the past decade regarding multiprocess services on Linux or other Unix-like systems?

I've been doing a good amount of reading and I have found many new features within Linux that seemed to come out of nowhere, such as the [process_vm_*v()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_readv.2.html) IPC functions, [signalfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html), [futexes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html), and as well as others, and have also heard tale of significant kernel improvements in the last few years which improve the way processes are managed and reduce overall overhead from managing many processes.

How significant are these new changes, and how drastic is the potential performance increase of these new functions/features?

Comment: You forgot [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) in your list. I believe that these new syscalls are more about development ease than about performance.